# LD_LIBRARY_PATH without export

Tags: c++, linux, shared-objects

I'm trying to run a program on a remote system on which I can't set environment variables (no access to export).  The problem I'm having is I can't set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to run my binary because I don't have (and can't get) permission.

I need a quick fix for this so I can run and test the application, I was wondering if there are any flags I can set when executing that will have the same effect - ie ./test -LD_LIBRARY_PATH="path-to-lib"

Looked around on the net and can't find anything =( help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, you can prepend executable with environment settings: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="path-to-lib" ./test`

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=Path-To-Lib: Command not found.
I did try this but got the above >.> Very prompt response though!

Comment: Shell is /bin/tcsh I believe

Comment: Don't you have an access to 'setenv' command? try `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH "path-to-lib" && ./test`

Comment: Switched to bash and everything worked well. Also tried the setenv and that worked too =) - Inspired you are my hero <3 Thanks a bunch